# Proving $\sqrt{31a+b+c} +\sqrt{31b+a+c} +\sqrt{31c+b+a}\le 3\sqrt{3}\cdot\sqrt{a+b+c+8}$? when $a+b+c+abc=4.$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, symmetric-polynomials, uvw

I came up with the inequality accidentally so there is no original proof so far. It would be great if you can give some useful help to prove it.

> **Problem.** Given non-negative real numbers $a,b,c$ satisfying $a+b+c+abc=4.$ Prove that
> $$\sqrt{31a+b+c} +\sqrt{31b+a+c} +\sqrt{31c+b+a}\le 3\sqrt{3}\cdot\sqrt{a+b+c+8}. $$

Equality occurs when $a=b=c=1$ or $a=b=2;c=0$ and its permuations.

I've tried to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality without success.

Indeed,$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{31a+b+c}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{31a+b+c}{b+c+xa}\cdot(b+c+xa)}\le \sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{31a+b+c}{b+c+xa}\cdot (x+2)(a+b+c).}$$
We'll prove $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{31a+b+c}{b+c+xa}\le \frac{27}{x+2}\cdot\frac{a+b+c+8}{a+b+c}.$$
Choose $x$ such that equality holds at $a=b=2;c=0$ $$1+2\cdot\frac{64}{2(x+1)}=\frac{81}{x+2}\iff x=7.$$Now, we need to prove
$$\color{black}{\sum_{cyc}\frac{31a+b+c}{b+c+7a}\le 3\cdot\frac{a+b+c+8}{a+b+c}}$$ which is not true for $a=b=\dfrac{1}{2}.$

Also, we can rewrite the OP as
$$\color{black}{\sqrt{31a+b+c} +\sqrt{31b+a+c} +\sqrt{31c+b+a}\le 3\sqrt{3}\cdot\sqrt{3a+3b+3c+2abc}. }$$

By using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{31a+b+c}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{31a+b+c}{b+c+xabc}\cdot(b+c+xabc)}\le \sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{31a+b+c}{b+c+xabc}\cdot 2(a+b+c)+3xabc.}$$
We'll prove $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{31a+b+c}{b+c+xabc}\le 27\cdot\frac{a+b+c+8}{2(a+b+c)+3xabc}.$$
It is not valid for $x$ value for equality occuring $a=b=2;c=0$ since $$1+2\cdot\frac{64}{2}>27\cdot\frac{12}{8}.$$

I truly hope we can find some nice ideas for my inequality. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Are you asking a question here?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an extremally nice problem!

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{31a+b+c}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{31a+b+c}{3a+2}\sum_{cyc}(3a+2)}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{31a+b+c}{3a+2}\leq\frac{9(a+b+c+8)}{a+b+c+2}.$$
Now, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove a linear inequality of $v^2$, which by $uvw$ says that it's enough to prove the last inequality for equality case of two variables.

Let $b=a$.

Thus, the condition gives $c=\frac{4-2a}{1+a^2}$ and after these substitutions we need to prove that:
$$(a-1)^2(2-a)(a^6+18a^5-19a^4-12a^3+24a^2-36a+36)\geq0,$$ which is true because by AM-GM

$$a^6+18a^5-19a^4-12a^3+24a^2-36a+36=$$
$$=a^6+9(a-2)^2+a^2(18a^3-19a^2-12a+15)\geq$$
$$\geq a^2(12(a^3-a^2-a+1)+6a^3-7a^2+3)\geq$$
$$\geq a^2(3a^3+3a^3+3-7a^2)\geq $$
$$\geq a^2\left(3\sqrt[3]{\left(3a^3\right)^2\cdot3}-7a^2\right)=2a^4\geq0$$

Comment: Very nice proof! Thank you.

Comment: @TATA box You are welcome! Bacteria helps again :)

Comment: The given condition does not depend on $v^2$ and $uvw$ turns out. Also, my Bacteria using wasn't good enough.